# Why my day is one day less from unix timestamp in php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I'm facing this problem where my `date` **shows one day less** i have this `unix timestamp` `1275429600`  which supposed to be `02-06-2010` but it is showing `01-06-2010`

**My Expected output:**  `02-06-2010` but getting `01-06-2010`

here is my code what i have tried.

```
$timestamp=1275429600;

echo gmdate("d-m-Y", $timestamp);
```

Comment: And your timezone setting? Because `1275429600` is `01 Jun 2010 22:00:00 GMT/UTC`, so expected output should not be `02-06-2010`

Comment: use this `date_default_timezone_set` to set default timezone..

Comment: i'm in asian time zone i,e asia/kolkata

Comment: @MarkBaker , sir here is demo http://phpio.net/s/3teg

Comment: http://www.convert-unix-time.com/?t=1275429600

Comment: @EaB Yes, and that "test" returns `01-06-2010` which is correct; you're wrong in assuming that it should be `02-06-2010`

Comment: @EaB gmdate is a GMT date and not a date in your timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope this will help you out.

Hope the first line of documentation [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) tells everything in itself.

`gmdate is Identical to the date() function except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
date_default_timezone_set("asia/kolkata");
echo date("d-m-Y", 1275429600);
```

**Output:**
`02-06-2010`

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to the timezone difference in your timezone & greenwich time zone.

`gmdate` behaves as `date` method except it returns the time returned of Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

```
GMT: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 22:00:00 GMT
Your time zone: 2010-6-2 03:30:00 GMT+5:30
```

Answer (score 0):

[gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) is a GMT date  and not a date in your timezone.

therefore you need to Use `Date('Z')` where `z` is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$timestamp=1275429600;

echo gmdate("d-m-Y", $timestamp + date("Z"));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the timezone 
`echo date_default_timezone_get();`

you can set the time zone

date_default_timezone_set(timezone);